# PHP - exec,shell_exec,system not working

Tags: php, exec

i read so many similar questions but nothing works with me

im using wamp 2.2 ,Apache 2.0 , PHP V5.3.8

safe_mode=off - disabled_functions deleted from php.ini i'm trying to exec

```
exec("chrome.exe google.com");
```

nothing happens and when i try

```
exec("calc");
```

the windows shows weird message to execute calc in different user although i changed the user for the apache service to Administrator and i verify the user using

```
exec("whoami");
```

where is the problem?

Comment: Is `chrome.exe` in your current working directory or the PATH variable?

Comment: when executing chrome.exe google.com on CMD it works well

Comment: i have to ask how are you running apache as Administrator, are you not running as a Service? and what OS as Windows Vista/7 does not have an Administration user

Comment: my user is the Administrator and my OS is win7 and i'm running the WAMP as admin and the apache service is running as admin

Comment: @MartinBarker `as Windows Vista/7 does not have an Administration user` - er... since when? How are you supposed to administer a computer without an administrator? Just because *your* machine doesn't have a *visible* administrator doesn't mean it's not there... Try running `control userpasswords2`

Comment: @FarokOjil I have not yet come up with a reliable way to launch desktop applications from a web server process. If the web server is running as *the same user you are logged in as* then you might be able to do it with [`COM`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.com.php) or [`DOTNET`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dotnet.php) but that's really getting out of the realms of where I  can offer useful advice. The root of the problem is that services have no associated desktop.

Comment: @FarokOjil See [this comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.exec.php#87943) in the PHP manual for an explanation of why what you are trying to do just won't work.

Comment: i tried control userpasswords2 and there is only one user (my user) and it's belong to Administrators group and i tried to do as the comment from php.net but nothing happened and finally i tried to make jar file that open chrome and it's work well but when i call it from php nothing happens .. is it because jar file consider as GUI program or what's the problem ?

Comment: @DaveRandom Windows 7 Does not have an "Administrator" Account it is a user group name, that contains the Administrator Elevation Privileges there is no Administrator User in Windows 7 or Vista. Its not like ubuntu where the root account still exists just locked out it, MS removed it for the Elevated Privileges System that has been used on Windows Domains For Years hence before hand and why another PC can Grant the Same Privileges to a User of another Windows 7/Vista Operating System on a LAN

Answer (score 0):

Environment path for CMD and php shell might not be the same.
You either have to give entire path of the file, or `export` the path of `chrome.exe` in php first

Also, I believe that `chrome.exe` opening a page requires XServer, php can't open graphical interfaces in shell. These commands are not passed to actual shell as a parent, so php file can't "launch" applications for you.

Please read specifics of the exec function:
[PHP `exec` Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

Also try adding `2> errors.txt` to see what are the errors if any in the execution of the programme.

--

The program needs to know what X server to connect to, and it needs to have permissions to connect to that server. You specify the X server with the DISPLAY environment variable; this will usually be set automatically if you are running the PHP program from a terminal in
X, or from a GNOME panel or something similar; however, if you are running the PHP script in some other manner, it likely won't know what X server to connect to.

X has various ways of specifying permission to connect to a server, but the most common one is using a file called ".Xauthority" in the users home directory. Because only the user who is logged in at the X server can read this file, they are the only user who can run GUI programs. So, if you start the PHP user as the same user who is logged in at the X server, you shouldn't have any problem with permissions. However, if the PHP program is running as a different user, you will have to give that user permission to access the X server.

Reference: http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/838364-cant-launch-graphical-apps-php-exec-ubuntu-8-04-system
(I know that link is for linux and won't have exact same solution for Windows, but `exec()` still needs to know which X interface to refer to)

Comment: There's usually no X server in Windows.

Comment: ok i get it .. i tried to make jar file that open chrome and it's work well but when i call it from php nothing happens .. is it because jar file consider as GUI program or what's the problem ?

Comment: Did you try error redirection using `yourcommand 2> errors.txt` ? It'll show what error program is throwing, which might help better in understanding the problem

Answer (score 0):

Stop Apache running as a service.

When windows runs a service it it is not running directly as the user that started the server or manages due to this it could well be starting chrome in a service environment so you wont see it load on your desktop there are 2 ways to get around this

Stop apache service browse to your apache directory and run httpd.exe manualy then try your script it should work or if it is not required to be running though a web request so it not using anything from the browser you can allow it to work with `c:\wamp\php\php.exe yourfile.php` (your php path should be replaced for `c:\wamp\php`)

Answer (score 0):

Try PHP script?

```
<?php shell_exec('notepad.exe');?>
```

It's working.